# Browser back button does not work on firefox and safari

Tags: themes, browser-compatibility

I created an online shop using WordPress, Woocommerce and one of the mikado themes. The problem is that when I go to a subpage and click the back button in my browser the url changes to the previous one but the page is empty. This happens only in Mozilla and Safari. Chrome, Opera and Edge work correctly.

[image: blank page]

Anyone have any idea what could be the problem, and how to deal with it?

*All plugins are updated to the latest version